# Import error running pytest - Google Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-functions, pytest, python-unittest, pytest-cov

My folder structure is like this

```
cloud_fn_dir
    cf1_dir
        main.py
        util.py
        requirements.txt
        test_main_cf1.py
    cf2_dir
        main.py
        requirements.txt
        test_main_cf2.py
    cf3_dir
        main.py
        requirements.txt
        test_main_cf3.py
```

I am executing unit tests and generating coverage report using command - `pytest -v --cov=main --cov-report=html`

If I am executing the command from inside the Cloud function folders i.e. **cf1_dir** or **cf2_dir** folders then the pytest command works as expected and executes the unit tests and generates reports inside that folder.

But I wish to execute all the unit tests at once and generate a single report and hence I tried to execute the same command from outermost folder i.e. **cloud_fn_dir** and encountered *Import Error* where the *test_main_cf3.py*  file is trying to import Class of cf1_dir main.py file.

Each of the test file is importing it's respective main.py file in it and creates an object and calls the methods to test. So when I execute the pytest command it is making the last test file i.e. test_main_cf3.py to import main of cf1_dir main.py and execute the methods. Pytest is trying to import the first encountered main.py class

How do I resolve this import error ?

Comment: Can you share the error screenshot?

Comment: I wont be able to share a screenshot but I can let know what exactly is happening.

Comment: Ok. Can you share the exact error message that you are getting?

Comment: Each of the test file is importing it's respective main.py file in it and creates an object and calls the methods to test. 

So when I execute the pytest command it is making the last test file i.e. test_main_cf3.py to import main of cf1_dir main.py and execute the methods. Pytest is trying to import the first encountered main.py class.